# How to Build apk with Phonegap Cli

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-cli

I Build a apk with phonegap cli, but problem is when I try to install apk with android phone get a `Parse Error "There is a problem parsing the package"`

What I try to build apk

1)phonegap `create my-app com.example.myapp my-app`

2)`phonegap platform add android`

at path `/path/to/myproject/platforms/android/cordova` run command `build --release`

I get apk at `path/myapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk`

I tried to install this apk to my phone get error `Parse Error "There is a problem parsing the package`"

As I search over net this may be problem with sign/key, I found [some solutions](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html)

first command not work `keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` get error

```
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Secondly [this is for online phone build](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) but I need to create apk with cli.

This also does not suit to me.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is your credentials correct Dinesh? Try using android studio with the current credential.

Comment: @user1872384, thanks , but sorry I not understand properly, can you explain what to do

Answer (score 10):

If your using the CLI for dev purposes just use `phonegap build android --debug --device`. Your don't need to worry about any signing identity issues this way. For release builds use the other method you were using `build --release`. After a release build you need to sign the `android-release-unsigned.apk` before it can be put on a device.

https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

keykool will work when invoke the cmd as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the apk for testing, just use `phonegap build --debug` NOT "--release". This will do the job and install with no problem.